# ExecutionContext causes Akka dead letter

Tags: scala, akka, executioncontext, akka-actor

For some reason I have to use gRPC and Akka at the same time. When this actor is started as a top actor, nothing goes wrong (in this little demo). But when it becomes a child actor, it cannot receive any messages, and the following is logged:

```
[default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6] [akka://default/user/Grpc] Message [AkkaMessage.package$GlobalStart] from Actor[akka://default/user/TrackerCore#-808631363] to Actor[akka://default/user/Grpc#-1834173068] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered.
```

The example core:

```
class GrpcActor() extends Actor {
    val ec = scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.global
    val service = grpcService.bindService(new GrpcServerImpl(), ec)
    override def receive: Receive = {
        case GlobalStart() => {
            println("GlobalStart")
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

I tried to create a new `ExecutionContext` like:

```
scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10))
```

Why is this happening, and how do can I debug a dead letters problem like this (no exception is thrown)?

Update:

Sorry I didn't list everything here. I used normal Main method to test `GrpcActor` as top actor, and ScalaTest to test it as child actor, which is a mistake.

```
class GrpcActorTest extends FlatSpec with Matchers{
    implicit val system = ActorSystem()
    val actor: ActorRef = system.actorOf(Props[GrpcActor])
    actor ! GlobalStart()
}
```

It is this empty test suite that active shutdown the whole actor system. But the problem is with this line

```
val service = grpcService.bindService(new GrpcServerImpl(), ec)
```

the delivery of `GlobalStart()` was delayed after the shutdown.

Without that line, message can be delivered before the shutdown.

Is this a normal behavior?

(My guess: it happened that the `GlobalStart()` was queued after the shutdown message with that line, which did some heavy work and made the difference in time)

Comment: Thank @chunjef for correcting my grammar mistakes and perfecting this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to address the problem is to make `service` a `lazy val`:

```
class GrpcActor extends Actor {
  ...
  lazy val service = grpcService.bindService(new GrpcServerImpl(), ec)
  ...
}
```

A `lazy val` is useful for long-running operations: in this case, it defers the initialization of `service` until it is used for the first time. Without the `lazy` modifier, `service` is initialized when the actor is created.

An alternative approach is to add a `Thread.sleep` in your test to prevent the actor system from shutting down before the actor has fully initialized:

```
class GrpcActorTest extends FlatSpec with Matchers {
  ...
  actor ! GlobalStart()
  Thread.sleep(5000) // or whatever length of time is needed to initialize the actor
}
```

(As a side note, consider using the Akka [Testkit](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/scala/testing.html) for your actor tests.)

Answer (score 0):

Add a supervisor strategy to its parent, add println to the actor lifecycle. There is something that kill your actor . Finally, if you provide a complete example maybe I can say more :)